Unique fixed points in compact space depend continuously on parameter
Let $V$ and $W$ be topological spaces and $\phi \colon V \times W \rightarrow W$ be continuous.
Assume that for all $v \in V$ there exists a unique fixed point $w_v = \phi(v,w_v)$.
If $W$ is compact (edit: and Hausdorff), then the fixed point map $V \rightarrow W$, $v \mapsto w_v$ is continuous.
I am interested in whether this result has a name or has been treated in a textbook.
It seems generally useful and is surprisingly easy to prove (see below).
I am surprised that I never encountered it before.
Given its simplicity yet elegance, it must have been written down somewhere.
Proof:
Suppose for contradiction the map $v \mapsto w_v$ is not continuous.
Then, there exists a point $v_0 \in V$, an open set $W_0 \subseteq W$ containing $w_{v_0}$, and a net $(v_a)_a$ converging to $v_0$ such that $w_{v_a} \notin W_0$ for all $a$.
By definition, $\phi(v_a,w_{v_a}) = w_{v_a}$.
Since $W$ is assumed compact, $(w_{v_a})_a$ has a convergent subnet with some limit $w_0 \in W$.
Since $(w_{v_a})_a$ is contained in the closed set $W \backslash W_0$, we also have $w_0 \notin W_0$.
On the other hand, by continuity$^1$, $\phi(v_0,w_0) = w_0$.
By uniqueness of the fixed point, $w_0 = w_{v_0} \in W_0$, a contradiction.
$^1$Edit:
in this step, we use that $W$ is Hausdorff because in non-Hausdorff spaces there are convergent nets with multiple limit points.
Without Hausdorffness, we can only conclude that $\phi(v_0,w_0)$ and $w_0$ are both a limit point of a subnet of $(\phi(v_a,w_{v_a}))_a$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155659

Is $W$ assumed to be Hausdorff?

@AnneBauval You are right, $W$ better be Hausdorff.

While my original search on MSE did not turn out fruitful, I found related posts on mathoverflow in addition to the one point to by Anne (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277057/continuity-of-mapping-sending-a-function-to-its-brouwer-fixed-point/277066#277066 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402607/continuity-of-kakutani-fixed-points/402673#402673). But none of them discuss if this is a known result or derived on the go. I keep my question here open since it is the only one I found with minimal topological hypotheses.
